# Android 10 kill foreground service when memory cleared

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, foreground-service

I run foreground service in android version 10 (Redmi note 8) its kill service when memory cleared but not kill when I remove app from recent by swipe. Any idea I check many answer but not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In chineese-ROMs battery optimization is very strict ,

For keeping foreground service ,

1. `Disable battery optimization` for the app
2. Enable `Auto-Start` for the app (for some work-manager cases)

Comment: Thats all you can do if you dont want to be blacklisted by google doze

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot and find the solution for foreground service kill in chaines manufacture.
https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/